# Killing vim processes with a shell script leaves .swp files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim

I developed a script that will kill all 'vim' processes working on 
xxx.log files:

```
ps -ef|grep vim|grep xxx.log|awk '{print $2}'|xargs kill -9
```

However, the .swp (swap) files remain for each vim instance killed.
How can I also delete the swap file in the same script, or other some short solution without searching for the location of the swap etc?

Comment: `pgrep` is proper way to `ps -ef|grep vim`. Also `fuser` is a better way to find pids of processes which have the file open. (Though you would have to call `fuser` on the swap file, since VIM doesn't keep the edited file open at all time.) `lsof -p <pid> | grep REG | grep xxx.log` is another alternative.

Comment: Yeah, have you read the **kill(2)** or **signal(7)** pages and what it says about `SIGKILL` signal?  SIGKILL doesn't allow a process to install a custom signal handler, so it always kills the program without giving it a chance to close files, rm temporary files and the like.  Try another signal (SIGTERM whose value is 15), try `kill -15` (or just `kill` as it's the default value) instead of `kill -9`. By the way, where did you read about signals and `-9` special value (you didn't read all about it) ???

Comment: On another side, if you `rm` the `.swp` files you are breaking the possibility of recover that files.  That's a dangerous thing.

Answer (score 14):

Drop the `-9` from `kill`; this will send the `TERM`(inate) signal to Vim, allowing it to clean up and remove the swap file (at least it did for me on Ubuntu).

By using `-9` / `KILL`, you don't give the process a chance to clean up. This should only be used for situations where it's absolutely necessary (e.g. when the process is hung or in an endless loop and doesn't react to external signals any more).

Comment: @Assafbaruch, but read the whole thing.  When you heard about `SIGKILL` or alias `-9`, you had to read the final note that says it doesn't allow the process to finish properly, so if you read that and do this, you'll be asking again in a couple of months.

Answer (score 2):

Since the swap file contains the name you deleted, you should be able to find it with a appropriate action, too.

However, killing an interactive editor like `vim` sounds very wrong on so many levels. You should really consider not doing that. In which situation is that desirable?

Comment: grepping some info from logs file. but when a file is open by other process like vim/less the script print an errors about these files:
main.log.2015-04-15.1246.gz: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
set noswapfile
```

to your vimrc. This will cause swap files to not be created in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, but that disables also the possibility of recover from crashes and lose your editions.